# Kotlin Android reflection get class in runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

I have a response from the server that returns me different objects and each object has a type. How I can match class in runtime with the type I get from the response? This code for example works but I am trying to get rid of the when statement and make it more dynamic.

```
sealed class Tile(
    private val id: String,
    private val type: String,
    private val title: String,
) {
    class RedTile(
        id: String,
        type: String,
        title: String,
        val stuff: String
    ) : Tile(id, type, title) {
        companion object {
            const val TYPE = "RedTile"
        }
    }
    class BlueTile(
        id: String,
        type: String,
        title: String,
        val value: Int
    ) : Tile(id, type, title) {
        companion object {
            const val TYPE = "BlueTile"
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun parseArray(jsonArrayString: String): List<Tile> {
        return JsonParser.parseString(jsonArrayString).asJsonArray
            .map { tileJsonObject ->
                tileJsonObject as JsonObject
                val tile = when (tileJsonObject.get("type").asString) {
                    Red.TYPE -> Red::class.java
                    Blue.TYPE -> Blue::class.java
                    else -> Red::class.java
                }
                Gson().fromJson(tileJsonObject, tile)
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a static `when` isn't really that bad, but I suggest moving it to a separate `Tile.getTileClassByType()` function for keeping the code clean. If you prefer to search for classes dynamically, then you can use the following:

```kotlin
companion object {
    private val tileClassesByType = Tile::class.sealedSubclasses
        .associateBy { it.simpleName!! }
    
    fun parseArray(jsonArrayString: String): List<Tile> {
        ...
        val tile = getTileClassByType(tileJsonObject.get("type").asString) ?: RedTile::class
        Gson().fromJson(tileJsonObject, tile.java)
        ...
    }

    fun getTileClassByType(type: String): KClass<out Tile>? = tileClassesByType[type]
}
```

Below is my original answer, before detailed information was provided in the question. It is discouraged as it is always better to avoid loading classes dynamically by name.

---

You can use [Class.forName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) from Java stdlib:

```kotlin
val type = tileJsonObject.get("type").asString
Class.forName("com.example.$type")
```

Just watch out for what you receive in this `type` field. If this data is untrusted then you should validate it before using, so the other side can't instantiate objects of arbitrary classes in your application.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I have an update question now sorry. With this it will work but now I need to set return value of parseArray to be List<Any> and I want List<Tile>. Any idea about it?

Comment: If you are sure that objects deserialized this way are always subtypes of `Tile` then just cast it: `Gson().fromJson(tileJsonObject, tile) as Tile`.

Comment: Thx man a lot! Last question ( sorry I am quite a newbie with Kotlin ) how to access Subclass of Tile? I need to access RedTile or BlueTile as the type will be for example BlueTile.

Comment: `RedTile` is nested inside `Tile`, so its full name is `Tile$BlueTile`. Don't ask why the dollar sign - this is a design decision made long ago by Java authors, not Kotlin. Anyway, please re-read my answer. After you provided the whole code, I think my original solution was really bad and it could be done much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I have one more question. If I do not want to use sealed classes and have all classes in one package that are a subtype of base class Tile, is there any chance to get all classes of the package and have the same functionalities? The problem with the sealed class is that if I have many different classes like RedTile that contain different properties this class can be a few thousand lines of code. Sorry if I bother you too much :)